# SPARQL Query: How to get all individual and data property assertions?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology

Same as you know if we retrieve the object property or data property and subclass can do that by joining them in one variable :

**Query 1**

```
SELECT ?x ?y
WHERE { ?x rdfs:subClassOf ?y.
?x rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty.
}
```

the `x` var it's same object property and subclass of other class
im need to join (all individual "`NamedIndividual`")
with object property or subclass .
the problem that is `( ?x rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual . )`
couldn't use `"?x"` in any other location same as :

```
?x rdfs:subClassOf ?y.
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT ?x ?y
WHERE { ?x rdfs:subClassOf ?y.
?x rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
}
```

**Query 3**

```
SELECT ?x ?y
WHERE { ?x rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty.
?x rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
}
```

So: Query 2 and Query 3 cannot be implemented.
how I can solve this problem?

Comment: what is your first query supposed to do? I doubt this is correct. And to be honest, I didn't understand what you're asking

Comment: It should be that none of these queries return any solutions, and nor should they. You're getting all of your classes, instances, and relations in a muddle. `?x` can only be one of these, you're treating it as two in all of these queries.

Comment: @PaulBrown modulo OWL 2 punning ... but that's why I was asking him what he is thinking his first query does and should do. For me it looks like he isn't aware of the difference between instance and schema data in RDF/OWL. And for the first query, I think he is more looking for the relationship between classes and properties via domain/range. But let's wait for a response from the TO. cheers